# An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll

Tags: c#, wcf

Estou tentando consumir um serviço porém da o erro:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll

E a mensagem:

> "Não foi possível localizar o elemento de ponto de extremidade padrão
>   que referencia o contrato 'ServicoEmpresa.IEmpresaServicoRemoto' na
>   seção de configuração do ServiceModel cliente. Isso pode ter ocorrido
>   devido à falta de um arquivo de configuração para o seu aplicativo ou
>   porque nenhum elemento de ponto de extremidade correspondendo a este
>   contrato pôde ser encontrado no elemento cliente."

Isso e problema no app.config?

Arquivo cliente

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>

    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttpBinding_IEmpresaServicoRemoto" />
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/PontoCerto.ServicoRemoto/EmpresaServicoRemoto/"
        binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding_IEmpresaServicoRemoto"
        contract="PontoCerto.ServicoRemoto.Contratos.IEmpresaServicoRemoto" name="BasicHttpBinding_IEmpresaServicoRemoto" />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>"

Arquivo do serviço:
>`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
    <membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="ClientRoleProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientRoleProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientRoleProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" cacheTimeout="86400" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="CustomMessage" type="PontoCerto.ServicoRemoto.Infraestrutura.CustomBehaviorExtensionElement, PontoCerto.ServicoRemoto,&#xD;&#xA;             Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
    <services>
      <service name="PontoCerto.ServicoRemoto.Servico.Service1">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/PontoCerto.ServicoRemoto/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="PontoCerto.ServicoRemoto.Contratos.IService1">
          <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <!-- Metadata Endpoints -->
        <!-- The Metadata Exchange endpoint is used by the service to describe itself to clients. -->
        <!-- This endpoint does not use a secure binding and should be secured or removed before deployment -->
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
      <service name="PontoCerto.ServicoRemoto.Servicos.EmpresaServicoRemoto">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/PontoCerto.ServicoRemoto/EmpresaServicoRemoto/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  contract="PontoCerto.ServicoRemoto.Contratos.IEmpresaServicoRemoto"
                  behaviorConfiguration="ClientEndpointBehavior">
          <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <!-- Metadata Endpoints -->
        <!-- The Metadata Exchange endpoint is used by the service to describe itself to clients. -->
        <!-- This endpoint does not use a secure binding and should be secured or removed before deployment -->
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ClientEndpointBehavior">
          <CustomMessage />

        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Provavelmente sim, tem como postar o app.config?

Comment: @DouglasMendes, acredito que o seu service possuia um EndPoint BasicHttpBinding e você alterou o mesmo para o WsHttpbinding. Se foi isto, tente remover a Service Reference e adiciona-la novamente.

Comment: @TobyMosque eu fiz essa alteração na tentativa de resolver o problema, realmente o projeto inicial era BasicHttpBinding. O mais engraçado é que utilizando o WCFTestClient funciona normalmente, porém quando tento instanciar o servico da erro este erro na classe "proxy" no cliente.

Comment: Está adicionando como Service Reference? O Service é uma WCF application ou uma WCF library?

Comment: E como Service Reference e é uma WCF library

Answer (score 3):

Tive exatamente o problema do Douglas, ainda encontrei outra peculiaridade. No AppConfig do projeto que é iniciado, o nome do contrato não pode ter o Namespace completo dele, exemplo:

Inicialmente configurei como:

```
<endpoint contract="Core.PCampoBom.Servicos" address="https://nfse.campobom.rs.gov.br/portal/Servicos" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServicosBinding"  name="ServicosPort"/>
```

Mas mesmo configurando isso em outro projeto, temos de colocar o Namespace interno do projeto que usa o webservice:

```
<endpoint contract="PCampoBom.Servicos" address="https://nfse.campobom.rs.gov.br/portal/Servicos" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServicosBinding"  name="ServicosPort"/>
```

É mais uma curiosidade, entrei aqui mais para agradecer.

Comment: Ok, a resposta do Douglas está correta, ele pode receber o seu voto a favor? Porque esta informação foi útil para mim, e quero que permaneça relevante para próximos usuários que encontrem esse problema.

Vou lá aumentar meus pontos de reputação depois eu volto.

Comment: @felipeAS você pode marcar a pergunta como favorita, ela fica visível para você no seu perfil

Answer (score 2):

Na Verdade este XML esta correto, o problema era bem mais básico, na minha arquitetura eu tenho o projeto com as telas e outro projeto com os controles, quando eu referenciava o serviço o Visual Studio deixava o arquivo App.config no projeto de controle porém o correto e deixar a configuração no projeto que inicia a aplicação.

Answer (score 0):

Meu caso era parecido com o do DouglasMendes. Pra resolver, foi só copiar a seção `system.serviceModel` do `app.config` para dentro da seção `configuration` do `web.config` do projeto que inicia a aplicação.